# How to save mobile number on heroku server

Tags: android, node.js, heroku

I want when someone signups with his mobile number through my android app (say abc) , the number must be stored or uploaded over the server. I don't know how to do that I have read a little bit about heroku volley etc. But didn't understand that. Is there anyone who wil be helpful for me.

Tell me how to save mobile number over server(heroku ) . I have zero knowledge about this.

Comment: You can't ask us to write code for you and the question is too broad.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)